# Allow user to add and manipulate text

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to figure out how to allow the user to be able to click a button to add a text field to the stage, type in their own text and then be able to freely move the text around with the mouse to position it where they want.

I have an idea on how to be able to position the text but not sure on the best way for managing the text input itself. I'd imagine it's quite difficult to be able to allow the user to 'click and drag' to draw a textbox and type in it / position it themselves? Is there an efficient way of doing this that I just don't know yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the position of a [DisplayObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7df5.html), of which [TextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html) is a child.

```
TextField myMovingTextBox = new TextField;
myMovingTextBox.x = 123;
myMovingTextBox.y = 436;

//Adding to the stage.
stage.addChild(myMovingTextBox);
```

You can make an instance of [TextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html) type-able by the user via its [type property.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#type)

```
myMovingTextBox.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
//Additional options
//myMovingTextBox.border = true;
//myMovingTextBox.restrict = "0-9";
```

You can learn the current mouse position via a [MouseEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/events/MouseEvent.html) triggered by the stage.

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
...
function onMouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void {
    //Mouse Pos
    event.stageX;
    event.stageY;
}
```

Comment: So can this be used to allow the user to move the textbox around with the mouse?